# CSS KEYFRAMES with links

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I have some images which scroll nicely in a keyframes

```
@-webkit-keyframes headImage /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0% {background:url(../images/homeBackground1.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;}
10% {background:url(../images/homeBackground2.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;}
30% {background:url(../images/homeBackground3.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;}
50% {background:url(../images/homeBackground4.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;}
70% {background:url(../images/homeBackground5.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;}
90% {background:url(../images/homeBackground1.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;}
}
```

However I want to make one of these images a clickable link, so for example i want homeBackground1.jpg to link to google.co.uk when it is visible but the others wont link anywhere when they are on display.

is there a way of doing this ?

Thanks

To expand a bit on this ,

the code to insert it into html is simply a

```
<section id="journey"> </section>
```

and CSS

```
#journey {
    height:400px;
/*  border-bottom: 5px solid #E64097;
    border-top: 5px solid #E64097;*/
    background: url(../images/homeBackground1.jpg) no-repeat left top #D8E3E9;
    -moz-animation:headImage 60s infinite; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation:headImage 60s infinite; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to see your HTML as well.

Comment: Why dont you just use a sprite and just change the background position?

Comment: If you want to add links, I suggest using a proper slideshow with absolutely-positioned inline images instead of background images.  [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) is a popular choice.

Comment: made some edits in main post thanks !

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks so much for the advice i have cycle2 up and running however i'm now struggling to make these images links if i do it in normal fashion, it simply take the image out of the loop and displays it separately thanks

Comment: You'd better post a separate question if you're having trouble with Cycle2. However, examine the documentation first -- there are many many examples on the site you can learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a sprite. So all of your images are joined in one large image but the user only can only see part of the image.

Then you just change the `background-position` using the key frames.
Here is a good [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/)

In the CSS you can use `from, to` or `%` as a time scale if you know the number of key frames that you need to use.

Comment: I don't think this answers his question about adding a clickable link to just one image.

Comment: yeah i'm happy with the animation as is it , obviously i'm more than happy to look into sprites if i cant get it to work in what i've done, its more so that its working perfectly i simply want one of those images to be a link. thanks